# real world experience of ext4yii

Tags: extjs, yii

I have been developing in php/mysql/extjs3 for nearly three years, using a home-made MVC approach, even in fairly big projects, but now I would like to switch to a php framework + extjs solution. My home-made solution works fine but I need something more solid and standardized, since I am close to switch from a one-man-band solution to a teamwork solution.

I am testing Codeigniter and Yii as frameworks and I found this ext4yii extension that look pretty promising. Anybody out there who is using this extension in the real world and wants to share her/his opinion?

Thanks a lot for you time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using Yii and ext4yii. There are several advantage. Since the MVC structure is built in for yii, you can not only save months of coding but also ramp up any new comers on the project and make sure they confirm to the MVC coding style. It is also properly documented.

ext4yii was a pleasant surprise to me, it provided the necessary bridge between ext3 and yii. It also has netbeans support, which is as important. My team was migrating from .NET and the ramp up on ext4yii/yii/ext3 was as good as it can get.

The only recommendation I have, try postgres instead of mysql. postgres is opensource.

Subash